# Is it possible to call REST api from lightning:container

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, rest-api, lightning-container

I'm seeing conflicting information:

On one hand, the `lightning:container` docs state that you can use this [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lightning-container) to [get a REST Session Key](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/container_npm_getrestapisessionkey.htm).

On the other hand, the spring 18 release notes say that [API Access for lightning containers has been revoked](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring18/release-notes/rn_lc_api_revert_cruc.htm).

I tried to build the [SOQL example app](https://github.com/developerforce/LightningContainerExamples/tree/master/ReactJS/Javascript/soql) listed in the documentation and I did in fact get a `401: This session is not valid for use with the REST API`.

So... I'm guessing it's not allowed anymore and this is just an example of Salesforce being horrible at updating their documentation?

Answer (score 1):

This is just another example of outdated documentation. As mentioned in the release notes, we cannot make REST api calls from lightning containers anymore.

Comment: Please do not use signature lines on Stack Exchange. Each post you make includes a link to your profile.